# rpy2 automatic NumPy conversion NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, rpy2

When trying to call the BayesTree R package from python with simple data, I am getting the error "NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call" even though all datum are positive real numbers.

## Source Code

```
import numpy as np
# R interface for python
import rpy2
# For importing R packages
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
# Activate conversion from numpy to R
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

train_x_py = np.array([[0.0, 0.0],
                       [0.0, 1.0],
                       [1.0, 1.0]])

# Any 3-length float vector fails for training y
train_y_py = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])

test_x_py  = np.array([[0.2, 0.0],
                       [0.2, 0.2],
                       [1.0, 0.2]])

# Create R versions of the training and testing data
train_x = rpy2.robjects.r.matrix(train_x_py, nrow=3, ncol=2)
train_y = rpy2.robjects.vectors.FloatVector(train_y_py)
test_x = rpy2.robjects.r.matrix(test_x_py, nrow=3, ncol=2)

print(train_x)
print(train_y)
print(test_x)

BayesTree = importr('BayesTree')
response = BayesTree.bart(train_x, train_y, test_x,
                          verbose=False, ntree=100)

# The 7th return value is the estimated response
response = response[7]

print(response)
```

## Code Output / Error

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    1    1

[1] 1 2 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.2  0.0
[2,]  0.2  0.2
[3,]  1.0  0.2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "broken_rpy2.py", line 32, in <module>
    verbose=False, ntree=100)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in (function (x.train, y.train, x.test = matrix(0, 0, 0), sigest = NA,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 7)
```

The error on line 32 to which it is referring is:

```
response = BayesTree.bart(train_x, train_y, test_x,
                          verbose=False, ntree=100)
```

**System Setup**

*Operating System:*
Mac OS X Sierra 10.12.6

*Python Version:*
Python 3.6.1

*R Version:*
R 3.4.1

*Python Packages:*
pip 9.0.1, 
rpy2 2.8.6, 
numpy 1.13.0

## Question

Is this my own user error, or is this a bug in rpy2?

Comment: Correction, I've tested this issue without using numpy. As long as the R matrices produce the same code output, the error occurs.

Comment: Editing the title in a minute, I reproduced the exact same problem in R. This is happening inside of the BayesTree package. There is no fix on the Python / Numpy / rpy2 side of things.

Comment: Instead of altering the title just post an answer (or what you consider to be the solution) yourself and accept it. :)

Comment: Thanks, fixing that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in the R package "BayesTree". You can reproduce the problem in R directly with the following code (assuming you have installed the BayesTree package).

```
train_x = matrix(c(0,0,1,0,1,1),nrow=3,ncol=2)
train_y = as.vector(c(1,2,3))
test_x = matrix(c(.2,.2,1.,.0,.2,.2),nrow=3,ncol=2)
result = bart(train_x,train_y,test_x,verbose=FALSE,ntree=100)
```